# How to return this particular addition operation with SQL?

Tags: sql

```
timestamp              account      exchange  value

1586932593708000000     mm2          binance  -882.34113908
1586932593711000000     mm2          binance  -882.34113908
1586932593716000000     mm1          binance  -1306.85072907
1586932593720000000     mm1          binance  -1306.85072907
1586932593723000000     mm1          binance  -1306.85072907
```

How can I return the sum of the latest values of each account for the corresponding exchange? For example in this one I want the sum of the values of row 2 and 5 since they are the last rows  corresponding to different accounts.

The result should be -882.34113908 + -1306.85072907 = 2189.19...

Note: I am using influxdb

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would help. I used window function however since we don't know which RDBMS and version you are using, I cannot guarantee that this will work for you

```
select sum(value) from (
  select 
    timestamp, 
    account, 
    exchange, 
    value, 
    row_number() over( partition by account order by timestamp desc) rn 
  from tbl
  where exchange = 'binance'
)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Window functions are standard SQL and available in almost all databases.  There is no need to apologize for using them.